# Why is this png being pushed to the left?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I cant seem to figure out why is this PNG image is being pushed to the left and I have a feeling that it is something to do with the SCSS code. It is not an issue with the file when the file exported from illustrator, it looks fine when viewing on desktop so it must be an issue with the SCSS.

Here is the banner file

```
import React from 'react';
import Typed from 'react-typed';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

import bg1 from '../../assets/img/generic/bg-1.jpg';
import dashboard from '../../assets/img/generic/CellBannerResize.png';

import Section from '../common/Section';

const Banner = () => {
  
  return (
    <Section className="py-0 overflow-hidden" image={bg1} position="center bottom" overlay >
      <Row className="justify-content-center align-items-center pt-8 pt-lg-10 pb-lg-9 pb-xl-0">
        <Col md={11} lg={8} xl={4} className="pb-7 pb-xl-9 text-center text-xl-left">
          <Button tag={Link} color="outline-danger" className="mb-4 fs--1 border-2x rounded-pill" to="/bulk-text-pricing">
            <span className="mr-2" role="img" aria-label="Gift">
              
            </span>
            Send Mass Text Messages Instantly
          </Button>
          <h1 className="text-white font-weight-light">
            Grow your
            <Typed
              strings={['Idea', 'Culture', 'Brand', '']}
              typeSpeed={70}
              backSpeed={40}
              className="font-weight-bold pl-2"
              loop
            />
            <br />
            Build your 
          </h1>
          <p className="lead text-white opacity-75">
          Connect instantly and directly to your 
          audience through text messaging at scale.
          </p>
          <Link className="btn btn-outline-light border-2x rounded-pill btn-lg mt-4 fs-0 py-2" to="/get-a-number">
            Get Started
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="play" transform="shrink-6 down-1 right-5" />
          </Link>
        </Col>
        <Col xl={{ size: 5, offset: 1 }} >  
          <Link to="/get-a-number" className="img-landing-banner">
            <img  src={dashboard} alt="" />  //<---- this is the image thats giving me trouble....
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default Banner;
```

Here is the .scss file

```
/*-----------------------------------------------
|   Landing banner style
-----------------------------------------------*/
.img-landing-banner{
  border-top-left-radius: $border-radius-soft;
  border-top-right-radius: $border-radius-soft;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-3rem);
  margin-bottom: -28rem;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: $box-shadow-lg;
  display: block;
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl){ margin-bottom: -18rem; }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg){ margin-bottom: -20rem; }
  &:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    transition: opacity 0.6s;
  }
  @include hover-focus{
    transform: translateY(-5rem);
    &:after{ opacity: 0; }
  }
}
@include media-breakpoint-only(xs){
  .landing-cta-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------
|  Back to top button   
-----------------------------------------------*/
.btn-back-to-top{
  background-color: $dark;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: $border-radius;
  left: 50%;
  top: -7.5rem;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------
|   Special Card
-----------------------------------------------*/
.card-span{
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  .card-span-img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background-color: $white;
    box-shadow: $box-shadow-sm;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  @include hover-focus{
    transform: translateY(-0.2rem);
    box-shadow: $box-shadow-lg;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please create a sandbox for this.

Answer (score 0):

*since the question is lacking in information to look at I will try to provide some easy fixes which are related to question.*

There can be couple of reasons to an element to get pushed aside, like [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), margin and padding properties of the parent nodes. and having no width and height property set to the element.

Since there is no working sandbox been provided in the question I will suggest some workarounds to fit an image inside the container.

Please take a look into [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property.

Other easiest solutions are

### **Parent having fixed width and height**

```
 /** Parent Node with Fixed width and height. **/
    
        <div class="imageHolder"> 
          <img src="link" />
        </div>
        
        .imageHolder{
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        }
        
        .imageHolder img{
        max-width: 100%
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width:auto;
        }
```

### **As Background-Image**

```
/** Background-Image, set the image  as a background image. **/
<div class="imagePlaceholder"/>
    
    .imagePlaceholder{
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('link');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    }
```